# Initializing RoleManager in ASP.NET Identity with Custom Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I changed the primary key for the user database from string to int using the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity), but I'm having difficulty initializing the Role Manager.  It used to be initialized using

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
```

How can I create the role manager using the new data?

Update: I'm using MVC 5 and EF 6.

Comment: Exact Same Issue which I am having, If I use `[Authorize( Roles="Admin")]` i get the following error: `The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your `ApplicationRoleManager` may look like this. because you have to inherit from your customRole class instead of `IdentityRole`.

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole, int>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<CustomRole, int> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

Then add following code to Startup.Auth.cs class if not currently exists.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Then you create and manage roles.

```
    var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

    const string roleName = "Admin";

    //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
    var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
    if (role == null)
    {
        role = new CustomRole();
        role.Id = 1; // this will be integer
        role.Name = roleName;

        var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for some reason the line is startup.auth.cs was missing on one project and the role manager was not initialising, this solved my issue thank you

Comment: Will `      [Authorize(Roles ="Edit")]` Automatically work after this?

Comment: It should be work as expected, no difference between manual insertion of roles directly in to database..

Comment: can you auto generate the `role.Id`... or is there a reason you would explicitly define `role.Id` as 1.

Comment: no, it depends on how you configure your database and identity roles table. In this example role.Id is integer and not a database auto generated field, so that I used it as 1 as it is the first role. You can auto generate role id, but you need to configure your entity framework to handle it.

Answer (score 4):

From your question i cannot determine if you are using the same frameworks (MVC & EF).

Recently i have created an MVC + EF solution using custom ApplicationUsers & IdentityRoles.
ApplicationUser is deriving from "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser".
ApplicationRoles are implemented without changes.

I have the following class:

```
// Configure the used in the application. RoleManager is defined in the ASP.NET Identity core assembly
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        }
    }
```

within configuration.cs (migrations)==> on 'update-database' this will be executed

```
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
    var applicationRoleAdministrator = new IdentityRole("Administrator");
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(applicationRoleAdministrator.Name))
    {
       roleManager.Create(applicationRoleAdministrator);
    }
// do some logic to find your applicationUserAdministrator
var applicationUserAdministrator = userManager.FindByName("Administrator");
userManager.AddToRole(applicationUserAdministrator.Id, applicationRoleAdministrator.Name);
```

withing startup.auth.cs the linkage towards the RoleManager:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Comment: Well I'm using MVC 5 and EF 6.  If you follow the tutorial, he creates custom classes for IdentityRole, UserStore, and RoleStore.  The compiler would not let me use. `new RoleStore<CustomRole>(context);`

Comment: Check my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<CustomRole,int>(new RoleStore<CustomRole,int,CustomUserRole>(context));
    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser,int>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser,CustomRole,int,CustomUserLogin,CustomUserRole,CustomUserClaim>(context));

   // In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User     
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin")){
    //first we create Admin rool   
        var role = new CustomRole();
        role.Name = "Admin";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    ////Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website     
    if (UserManager.FindByName("Admin") == null){
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Admin" };
        string userPWD = "adminadmin";
        var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);
        if (chkUser.Succeeded){
            var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin")
            ;
        }
    }
```