# Can't add new role on Seed method after change Identity from string to int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

After following [this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) article to "Change Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity" I have an Issue when adding a new Role in Seed method.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column `'Id'`, table `'X.dbo.AspNetRoles'`; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

My code is:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var roleStore = new CustomRoleStore(context);
    var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);

    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrador"))
        roleManager.Create(new CustomRole("Administrador"));
}
```

And the error occurs on the last line: roleManager.Create...

Plus to the tutorial I have this implementation in IdentityConfig.cs:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole, int>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<CustomRole, int> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore) { }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

[image: Is Identity = False]

**Edit 1**

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to provide Id for the new role as it is now integer. var rolename = "Administrador"; var role = new CustomRole();
        role.Id = 1; // this will be integer
        role.Name = roleName; - somthing like that. Or change it to auto increment id field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174576/initializing-rolemanager-in-asp-net-identity-with-custom-roles/26177007#26177007

Comment: Yes, it's what I want, change it to auto increment, how can I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Add Id property to your CusatomRole class and decorate it with  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: When I try this, this error appears: "The item with identity 'Id' already exists in the metadata collection."

Comment: Post your ApplicationDbContext code, You could fix this on model biding

Comment: Remove previous change and apply below mentioned changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give some work around for this. You can manually update your CustomRole table on database to have auto increment values. Then override the EF OnModelCreating as explains below.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBinder modelBinder)
    {
        modelBinder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("CustomRole"); // This may be not needed, check it.

        modelBinder.Entity<CustomRole>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: I will mark as answer until someone send a better approach to what I need in a production enviorment. Dont like to change things in database directly. Anyway thanks for now

Comment: Yes, this will be just only for your development environment. I hope someone will help you on this in proper way.

Comment: @DSR if id is string?