# Error in adding roles to ASP.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My code is like this

```
    namespace DiagnosisApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DiagnosisContext")
        {
        }
    }
}

    namespace DiagnosisApp.DAL
{
    public class DiagnosisInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DiagnosisContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DiagnosisContext context)
        {
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new
                UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new
                RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

            string name = "Admin";
            string password = "123456";


            //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(name))
            {
                IdentityResult roleresult = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(name));
            }

            //Create User=Admin with password=123456
            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = name;
            IdentityResult adminresult = userManager.Create(user, password);

            //Add User Admin to Role Admin
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                IdentityResult result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, name);
            }
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}

    namespace DiagnosisApp.DAL
{
    public class DiagnosisContext : DbContext
    {
        public DiagnosisContext()
            : base("DiagnosisContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DiagnosisInitializer());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything looks okay to me, But this throws an error

> The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

At line

```
 if (!roleManager.RoleExists(name))
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174576/initializing-rolemanager-in-asp-net-identity-with-custom-roles possible duplicate

Comment: @MethodMan I don't think so, Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your seed method

```
protected override void Seed(DiagnosisContext context)
```

is accepting a  `DiagnosisContext` which only inherits from a vanilla DbContext. You should pass in `ApplicationDbContext`

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
```

There is no IdentityRole on DbContext.

Comment: Is it correct to pass two different contexts? when i tried i got some error.

Comment: Error:Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DiagnosisApp.DAL.DiagnosisContext>.Seed(DiagnosisApp.DAL.DiagnosisContext)' has some invalid arguments C:\Asembla\Thajes\DiagnosisApp\DiagnosisApp\DAL\DiagnosisInitializer.cs 40 13 DiagnosisApp

Comment: Make this DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DiagnosisContext> use ApplicationDbContext for the generic type argument as well.

Comment: I can't do that, my whole application is based on DiagnosisContext

Comment: No it's not. Your membership system is based on ApplicationDbContext. Nothing to do with DiagnosisContext.

Comment: Yes, But the other part of the application is using DiagnosisContext. SO can't Avoid it.

Comment: I think I am missing what you are saying. can you please add a code sample for this

Comment: The code you have is sufficient to explain the problem. You're getting an error that IdentityRole is not a part of the current context. The reason is just as per the message... there is no IdentityRole on DiagnosisContext because DiagnosisContext inherits only from DbContext. Perhaps your misunderstanding is  based on an erroneous belief that you have to call DiagnosisInitializer from within DiagnosisContext? You can stick it in Global as it's really only a dev tool anyway. It's not like you'd use it "always on" in production right?

Answer (score 1):

Check if DiagnosisContext class has valid signature as below:

```
public class DiagnosisContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
```

or

```
public class DiagnosisContext : IdentityDbContext
```

Comment: I have added my DiagnosisContext  class to question, Its already inheriting from DbContext, Multiple inheritance won't be allowed, right?